# Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/hello] threw exception

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

When I run the code in the student_form.xhtml I am getting the error underneath. I do not know why the error is partly in english and german. in the student_form.xhtml the following warning `Unknown tag (f:selectItem).` is being displayed.

> Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/hello] threw exception

**student_form.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

<h:head>
    <title>Student Registration Form</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form>
        <!-- JSF will call student.setName(string firstName) -->
            First name: <h:inputText id="firstName"
            value="#{student.firstName}" />
        <br />
        <br />

            Last name: <h:inputText id="lastName"
            value="#{student.lastName}" />

        <br />
        <br />

            Country:            
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{student.country}">
            <f:selectItem itemvalue="Brazil" itemLabel="Brazil" />
            <f:selectItem itemvalue="France" itemLabel="France" />
            <f:selectItem itemvalue="Germany" itemLabel="Germany" />
            <f:selectItem itemvalue="India" itemLabel="India" />
            <f:selectItem itemvalue="Turkey" itemLabel="Turkey" />
            <f:selectItem itemvalue="United kingdom" itemLabel="United kingdom" />
            <f:selectItem itemvalue="United States" itemLabel="United States" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>



        <br />
        <br />


        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="student_response" />
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

**student_response.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <title>Student Confirmation</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
    <!-- JSF will call student.getFirstName() -->

        The student is confirmed: #{student.firstName} #{student.lastName}

        <br/> <br/>

        The student's country: #{student.country}

    </h:body>
</html>
```

**Student class**

```
package com.stack;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String country;

    public Student(){

    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }


}
```

**error**

```
Jun 19, 2016 7:40:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/hello] threw exception [Error Parsing /student_form.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 26] Präfix "f" für Element "f:selectItem" ist nicht gebunden.] with root cause
javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /student_form.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 26] Präfix "f" für Element "f:selectItem" ist nicht gebunden.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:444)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doMetadataCompile(SAXCompiler.java:427)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.metadataCompile(Compiler.java:130)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:499)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$200(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:209)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:207)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:92)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:146)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:63)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:320)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:250)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:113)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:241)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" in your html tag

```
<html lang="en"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" >
```